# jquery: how to disable a function with `.click(function() {`

Tags: jquery

How can i disable a jquery function with `.click(function() {`

for example i need to disable the following code, if the user clicked on `.click(function() {`

```
    function infinity() {
$.ias({container:'#dle-content',item:'.item_p',pagination:'.page_navigation1',next: 'div#page_navigation1 a:last-child',loader:'<p><center><img src="{THEME}/images/loa$
}
infinity();
```

what i've tried:

```
$("#pages_navigation").off('infinity');
$("#pages_navigation").unbind('infinity');
```

Comment: Are you binding infinity on click event or what?!

Comment: $("#pages_navigation").off('infinity');  Doesnt mean anything! Off() is for events, not event function callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use off() for jq 1.7+:

```
$('#myelem').off('click');
```

for jq < 1.7, use unbind instead:

```
$('#myelem').unbind('click');
```

Comment: already tried that. didn't work

Comment: Your code should be: $('#myelem').click(infinity);   Then to unbind it, use: $('#myelem').off('click');